# how does <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> really work?

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I know that in spring there are two type of method to create proxy, one is use **JDK proxy** and another is use **CGLIB**. And I also know the difference between these two type of proxies. But I can not understand the **AOP** in spring.

for example:

```
public interface Performance {
    void perform();
}

public class AnotherPerformance implements Performance {

    @Override
    public void perform() {
            System.out.println("AnotherPerformance is performing");
        }
    }
}
```

Aspect -

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.xxx.aspect.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void perform(){

    }

    @Before("perform()")
    public void silenceCellphones(){
        System.out.println("silence cell phones");
    }

    @Before("perform()")
    public void takeSeats(){
        System.out.println("Taking seats");
    }

    @AfterReturning("perform()")
    public void applause(){
        System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!!");
    }

    @AfterThrowing("perform()")
    public void demandRefund(){
        System.out.println("Demanding refund!!!!");
    }


    @Around("perform()")
    public void watchPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){
        try {
            System.out.println("silence cell phones");
            System.out.println("Taking seats");

            joinPoint.proceed();

            System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!!");
        } catch(Throwable e){
            System.out.println("Demanding refund!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Client code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-xxx.xml");
    AnotherPerformance performance = ctx.getBean("anotherPerformance",AnotherPerformance.class);
}
```

When I remove `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` from 
spring configuration file, the error was thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'anotherPerformance' is expected to be of type 'com.aspect.xmlconfig.AnotherPerformance' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
    at com.aspect.xmlconfig.AnotherMain.main(AnotherMain.java:22)
20:47:21.028 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Failed to convert bean 'anotherPerformance' to required type 'com.springinaction.aspect.xmlconfig.AnotherPerformance'
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2 implementing com.springinaction.aspect.Performance,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'com.aspect.xmlconfig.AnotherPerformance'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2 implementing com.aspect.Performance,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'com.aspect.xmlconfig.AnotherPerformance': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
    at com.aspect.xmlconfig.AnotherMain.main(AnotherMain.java:22)
```

`proxy-target-class=true` use **CGLIB** to create proxy, but here the class `Perfromance` is a interface, why does spring can not create proxy object use JDK dynamic proxy?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC when you create a proxy with JDK dynamic, java.lang.reflect.Proxy will be the superclass of all dynamic classes created by JDK Dynamic, whereas with CGLIB itself create the proxy by subclassing the target class.

So CGLIB proxy is definitely AnotherPerformance type, but when it goes to the JDK Dynamic, java.lang.reflect.Proxy will be your type. It's Proxy that implements your interface, and also calling your actual target class when call is made outside of proxy.